# Pass modified result of one observable from one Class to another Class , in RxJava way?

Tags: android, kotlin, observable, rx-java2

I want to pass result from class B to class A as an observable

1. Api class makes network call and pass myResult (thru Single.fromCallable()) to class B
2. Class B receives myResult and modifies it
3. Class B needs to pass the modified result (or any error) to Class A, where initial call was made (class A calls ClassB's method in order to make an api call)

   , how do I do step 3 in reactive /RxJava way?

not sure if Map is what I am looking for but any working example will help massively. Also the separation Between Class A , Class B and Api class is must have

```
Class A {
         CalssB.MethodB()
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribeBy(onError = {//handle error
                    }, onSuccess = {
                       // handle success i.e myResult = it
                    })
    
    }
```

---

```
 Class B {
           fun methodB(): Single<MyResult> {
    
            var myResult = MyResult()
    
            api.getMyResult()
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribeBy(
                            onSuccess = {
    //3 - here is I need help , modify result and pass it as an observable to class A where (CalssB.MethodB() is called)
                            }
                    , onError = {
    //3 - here is I need help , pass Error to Class A where (CalssB.MethodB() is called)
                    }
                    )
    
}
```

---

```
Api {

 public Single<MyResult> getMyResult() {
return Single.fromCallable(() -> doGetMyResult()); //network call
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly you want to retrieve data in ClassA and modify it in ClassB, then pass it back to ClassA. It sounds like you could make it with simple `Single.map`.
Add method to your ClassB that returns `Function<Result,ModifiedResult>`and use `.map(ClassB.methodThatReturnsFunction())` before `subscribeBy` in ClassA.

Second option is adding similar method, but method that returns

`SingleTransformer<Result,ModifiedResult>` 
and use it with
 `Single.compose`.

That way you compose your own stream and encapsulate it inside ClassB.

Hope that helps.